# Pivot a 3 joins tables SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv, output, pivot-table, qsqlquery

I have a query that joins two tables. The result I need to be pivot on the `QuestionID`, because now the `QuestionID` is vertically instead to be horizontally

Here is my query

```
select

b.TOKEN,a.[GUBSRVY_TITLE], a.[QuestionID],b.[GURSRVQ_TEXT],(cast(isnull([GORSRVR_RESPONSE_1], 0) as int) 
+ cast(isnull([GORSRVR_RESPONSE_2],0) as int) + cast(isnull([GORSRVR_RESPONSE_3],0) as int) 
+ cast(isnull([GORSRVR_RESPONSE_4],0) as int) + cast(isnull([GORSRVR_RESPONSE_5],0) as int))
as RESPONSE
from [QuestionMappingNew3] a 
left join [AUB_ICE_SURVEY_ANSWERS_MV] b
on a.[GUBSRVY_TITLE] = b.[GUBSRVY_TITLE]
join [AUB_ICE_SURVEY_ANSWERS_SUMMARY_MV] c
on b.[GUBSRVY_TITLE] = c.[GUBSRVY_TITLE]
where TERM = '2020'
```

The output is

```
    TOKEN   GUBSRVY_TITLE   BlueQuestionID  GURSRVQ_TEXT    RESPONSE
939 201420-BUSS-350D-1-L-Bizhan Azad    Q2Row1  The instructor was prepared for the class   5
939 201420-BUSS-350D-1-L-Bizhan Azad    Q3Row1  The instructor was prepared for the class   5
939 201420-BUSS-350D-1-L-Bizhan Azad    Q4Row1  The instructor was prepared for the class   5
```

What I need its to have the `QuestionID` in rows. How could I do this with pivot

Thanks you in advance

Comment: Any chance you'd post your table structures, sample data for each table along with the desired result?  Or even better create a sql fiddle.

Comment: Hi I tried to create a sql fiddle but It gave me a structure error. When I run this query from sql server I get no error. 
The desire result its to have all the Q2Row1.... in rows means that all what is inside QuestionID Column will become rows. Thanks